# Shrinking background image in sync with Div size reduction

Tags: html, css, media-queries, flexbox

I have a ticket site with a fixed width of 650px that I am trying to display better on mobiles and make responsive.

The booking system has divs (auto generated by the server) overlaying a venue image that is set as a background image url. The problem is if I set certain div widths to 100% such as the container or background image url, all the divs then go all out of place and will not align as originally set against the fixed width.

https://jsfiddle.net/04my0hvc/
Screenshot https://s9.postimg.org/qdh8ihdlr/screenshot.jpg

**Could flexbox shrink come into play here, or perhaps a Zoom option when going below 650px?**

Some sample code is below but I cannot fully present all the code as the bulk is Javascript used to generate the divs too that I can't access. But please see JSFiddle and screenshot above.

```
  <div id="theatre">
      <div id="bmessage">Select the seats that you need.</div>
      <div id="seats" style="height:650px;background: url('http://i.imgur.com/qn56yss.gif') no-repeat center top;"><div class="s1 std grey" si="0" title="A16" style="top:75px; left:233px;"></div><div class="s1 std grey" si="1" title="A15" style="top:75px; left:251px;"></div><div class="s1 std grey" si="2" title="A14" style="top:75px; left:269px;"></div><div class="s1 std grey" si="3" title="A13" style="top:75px; left:287px;"></div></div>
```

Comment: What container? If the container is bigger than the image, the content will adjust to the container and not the background image. Maybe set another container the width of the background image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a container div and then have the background image `background-size` property value set to `contain`.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/04my0hvc/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="theatre">
 <div class="container">
    <div id="bmessage">Select the seats that you need.</div>
    <div id="seats" style="height:650px;background: url('http://i.imgur.com/qn56yss.gif') no-repeat top left; background-size: cover">
    <div class="s1 std grey" si="0" title="A16" style="top:75px; left:233px;"></div>       
    <div class="s1 std grey" si="1" title="A15" style="top:75px; left:251px;"></div>
    <div class="s1 std grey" si="2" title="A14" style="top:75px; left:269px;"></div>       
    <div class="s1 std grey" si="3" title="A13" style="top:75px; left:287px;"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Set the `background-size` property to `contain`

Comment: I think this is going to be more compilcated than I thought, the divs are set as absolute so stay where they are.If set to relative they go all over the place http://i.imgur.com/UjyQvIE.jpg

Comment: If you set the parent element to relative, they will be positioned to that container and should stay in place?

Comment: Even if the seats are set as absolute in px?

Comment: Ahhhh no. Any reason you can't you a relative unit such as `%`?

Answer (score 0):

Use   **background-size: contain;** to the div which contains a id "seats"